# How to strip formatting of csvreader in python login script

Tags: python, csv, authentication, formatting

Hi I am trying to make a login script for an assignment I am nearly there but my csvreader output has weird formatting around it for example it shows the string ['password'] instead of just password which is what I need. I would like to avoid using a regex if possible.

```
import csv

def createAccount():
    userCreated = False
    print("CREATE AN ACCOUNT!")
    while not userCreated:
        username1 = input("Enter Username:")
        password1 = input("Enter Password:")
        if username1 and password1 != "":            
            userCreated = True
            print("ACCOUNT CREATED!")
            loginDetails1 = username1+password1
            with open("test234.csv", 'w') as output:
              writer = csv.writer(output)
              writer.writerow([loginDetails1])
        if userCreated is not True:
            print("ENTER ALL DETAILS!")


def login():
    loggedIn = False
    while not loggedIn:
        username = input("Username:")
        password = input("Password:")
        loginDetails = username+password
        with open("test234.csv", "r") as csv_file:
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                for line in csv_reader:
                    if loginDetails == line:
                        loggedIn = True
                        print("Logged in")
                if loggedIn is not True:
                    print("Wrong username or password")
                    print(line)
                    print(loginDetails)


createAccount()
login()
```

Output looks like this [image]

Comment: what is contained in your test234.csv file?

Comment: in the test234.csv is the output from the create account function which is danp in this example. When i open the csv it shows the text normally with no funny[''] enclosing it.

Comment: Looks like each time you print(line) you're printing a single item list. What is it you want print(line) to do?

Comment: I am using print line for testing only. Really i need loginDetails to == line. Which it does not beacuse of the [''] around the string.

Comment: csv.reader does not return a string, it returns an iterable. If you want to make a comparison with a string as a conditional you need to convert the output to a string first.

Comment: aah thank you Paula. This makes sense. I will try this option

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone `csv.reader` indeed does return an iterable, but that's not the problem here since the reader is being iterated. The issue is that `line` is a list, not a string.

Comment: as I said above ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your password is in `line[0]`. The reader separates each line into fields based on the separator and quoting, so each line is a *list of strings*.

Comment: Thank you. i did what you said and the formatting dissapeared leaving behind just the contents of the line.

Comment: @DanA It works, but there is a subtle difference - `line[0]` is only "the contents of the line" because your line happens to have *only one field*. It's a .csv file, so each line is expected to have multiple values separated by a comma. For example, username and password as "dan,p". Using this example, `line[0]` would be "dan", and `line[1]` would be "p". While I expect this is a toy example, you probably want to compare the fields discretely in case there is another record that happens to be the same when concatenated, for example a username of "da" and a password of "np".